# sscanf() skipping delimiter & width

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, printf, scanf

I am writing an assembler for 6502 and trying to read the instructions and opcode data from a file I prepared. Using `sscanf` to store data and it only worked partially...

File:

```
ADC,Im,69,2    
ADC,ZP,65,2
ADC,ZPx,75,2
ADC,Ab,6D,3
ADC,Abx,7D,3
ADC,Aby,79,3
...
```

Here is only part of the code related to the problem. `fgets` works fine. Problem line commented below. Will upload more if needed.

Code:

```
  FILE *fp = ...
  char bf[15];
  char name[3];
  char mode[3];
  char op[2];
  int bytes;

  while (fgets(bf,15,fp)) {
    //below is the problem line
    sscanf(bf, "%3[^,],%3[^,],%2[^,],%d", name, mode, op, &bytes);
  }
  printf("%s,%s,%s,%d\n", name, mode, op, bytes);
```

Output:

```
ADCIm,Im,69,2
ADCZP,ZP,65,2
ADCZPx75,ZPx75,75,2
ADCAb,Ab,6D,3
ADCAbx7D,Abx7D,7D,3
...
```

Expected to be (just like the file format):

```
ADC,Im,69,2
ADC,ZP,65,2
ADC,ZPx75,75,2
ADC,Ab,6D,3
ADC,Abx7D,7D,3
...
```

It seems that op and bytes all work alright, but there are something wrong with the name and mode variables, even though I contained the width and delimiter in the argument.

Comment: Lesson learned -- (1) all strings require *nul-termination*, (2) *Don't skimp on buffer size!* If the max field you anticipate is `3` use `16` if you think your max line could be `300` chars, size the buffer at `1024`; and (3) remember, it is always better for the buffer to be `10,000` bytes too long than `1` byte too short.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, lessons learned:)

Comment: Also, always, *always*, check return value of `scanf` family of function. Otherwise parse error will make everything go haywire in your program (for example because of uninitialized variables with random data). And parse error may be caused by bug in your format string which you never noticed, or a valid input which you forgot to take into account, too, not just because of malformed input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's not `sscanf` that is at fault.  You have undefined behavior due to buffer overruns -- `printf` knows nothing about the fact that your strings are not null-terminated, and it will continue printing characters until it finds a `'\0'`.

To stop it from doing that, you can supply a maximum field width in the format specifier:

```
printf("%.3s,%.3s,%.2s,%d\n", name, mode, op, bytes);
```